# Can't change backcolor of TabPage with DevExpress WinForms XtraTab

Tags: winforms, devexpress

I'm using a DevExpress WinForms XtraTab control v11.2 and I can't get the tab page background color to change.  It's stuck on transparent.  I've set colors on the XtraTab's AppearancePage.PageClient and there was no effect.

If you throw a default XtraTabControl out you get two tabs that are both white in the main area.  I want this area to be grey.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to what you're doing, set the XtraTabControl's `PaintStyleName` to Standard or PropertyView or one of the other non-Default styles to get the look you want:

Here's an example of dragging in the XtraTabControl and only changing the `PaintStyleName` property:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the control's look and feel is set as skin then from what I'm aware you can't change the backcolor.

In order to actually do so you have two options:

1) Use devexpress SkinEditor utility to create a skin with the colors you want.

2) Set default look and feel to false, the style to flat, then you will be able to choose what color you want (keep in mind since you will be disabling the skin it won't look as good so the first option might be better).

```
this.xtraTabControl1.LookAndFeel.Style = DevExpress.LookAndFeel.LookAndFeelStyle.Flat;
            this.xtraTabControl1.LookAndFeel.UseDefaultLookAndFeel = false;
            this.xtraTabControl1.TabPages[0].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gray;
```